# How to fix "Property not exist error" with Discriminating Unions types?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to refactor a project in TS (still learning the basics, sry) and I set up the typing of the authentication user roles in this way:

```
export interface Guest {
  isGuest: true;
  isManager: false;
  isAdmin: false;
}

export interface LoggedUser {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  isActive: boolean;
  email: string;
  userId: number;
  username: string;
  isManager: boolean;
  isGuest: false;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

export type User = Guest | LoggedUser;
```

I then set up a React Context and a hook for getting user information throughout the application. The hook retrieves all the info (name, last name, email, etc) correctly but then I have a type error.

```
const user = useUser();
const { email } = user;
```

When I try to use properties of the logged user, TypeScript still check for both types even if I set them up as conditional (one OR the other)
I get this error:

```
Property 'email' does not exist on type 'User'.
  Property 'email' does not exist on type 'PublicUser'.
```

I've found a sort of workaround with a simple if statement, but I don't get why the compiler doesn't accept the discriminating union.

Answer (score 1):

`Typescript` is working fine. If you define multiple return types and you don't cast the result to any specific type, `Typescript` will assume that the given result's safe properties are the ones that are available in both types.

You can set the type to `LoggedUser`:

```
const user = useUser();
const { email } = user as LoggedUser;
// email will be value or null
```

Another approach is to define differently your types to avoid setting the return type on every function call (I prefere `type` notation instead of `interface`):

```
export type CommonInfo = {
  isGuest: boolean;
  isManager: boolean;
  isAdmin: boolean;
};

export type LoggedOnly = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  isActive: boolean;
  email: string;
  userId: number;
  username: string;
};

export type Guest = CommonInfo & Partial<{ [K in keyof LoggedOnly]: never }>;
// or: export type Guest = CommonInfo & Partial<{ [K in keyof LoggedOnly]: null }>;
// or: export type Guest = CommonInfo & Partial<LoggedOnly>;

export type LoggedUser = CommonInfo & LoggedOnly;
export type User = Guest | LoggedUser;
```

That way you will avoid the type error when executing `const { email } = useUser();`.

I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know the syntax of your first code block, the one in which the LoggedUser type is inside the brackets. Do you know how it's called? I want to read something in the TS docs, seems very handy.

Comment: My wrong, I edited the answer already. You have the TS docs here: [Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is smart enough to discriminate between the two, you just have to actually check the field that's doing the discriminating, i.e. `isGuest`:

```
const user = useUser()

if (user.isGuest) {
  // can access isGuest, isManager, isAdmin here
} else {
  // can access all the LoggedUser properties here
}
```

It's up to you what your component actually *does* when it doesn't have an email, but from the types you've listed, that looks like a valid situation.

Edit:

> I've found a sort of workaround with a simple if statement, but I don't get why the compiler doesn't accept the discriminating union.

This is not a workaround, it's the point of Typescript: something that's a `User` type *might* have an `email`, but it also might not, because it's a `Guest`. Typescript makes you actually check, instead of assuming.